# If IIS and/or SQL Server queue up requests, where can those queues be monitored?

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-services, iis, asmx

I have a function exposed through an ASMX web service that upserts data into a SQL Server database. I call it asynchronously like this from a console app:

```
theClient.DoMyFunctionAsync(myParam);
```

It works great, but I have some questions ...

If I call the function 100 or 500 or 1000 times as fast as I can, where would the bottle-necks lie and how would I monitor them?

I assume IIS would either stop receiving or queue up the requests? If it queues them up, where is that queue and how can I monitor it?

I know the .NET web service handles database connection pooling. Does the connection pool have a queue mechanism that stores the requests for a while until a connection from the pool is available? And if so, how would I monitor that queue?

Comment: Your bottleneck would be SQL Server side Disc IO. pretty much. Like 95% of all SQL perforamnce issues are either missing indices or.... too slow storage.

Comment: There is a nice article here http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/ explaining how SQL Server works.

Answer (score 1):

For asp.net, check the counter "Requests Queued" using Perfomance Monitor.
Details and other counters here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4(v=vs.100).aspx